# Can you use Azure data sync agent for ongoing replication between Azure SQL Server and AWS SQL Server on RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-rds

Since AWS DMS doesn't support reading CDC from Azure SQL Server, can you use Azure data sync agent for ongoing replication from Azure SQL Server to AWS SQL Server on RDS (one direction)? Do you need to involve any other services or tools, assuming networking is properly set up? Anything to consider before the replication?